# How can I use an emulator running on a docker container from another docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, android-emulator, adb

In order to execute my tests in any jenkins agent without needing any extra setup, I wanted to have everything running in Docker.

My first approach was use a base image with all I needed there, that is my application code, Android SDK, Flutter, Emulator and an emulator image. Sadly, image size went higher than 10 GB so I decided to split responsibilities:

- My base image will only contain Androi sdk. The following images will inherit from it:
- Image 1 will have my app with a volume mounted and Flutter in order to build/test.
- Image 2 will have an emulator running.

This is the docker-compose of my setup:

```
---

version: '3'

services:
  flutter:
    build:
      args:
        - "FLUTTER_CHANNEL=stable"
        - "FLUTTER_VERSION=1.2.1"
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileFlutter
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: ["flutter", "test"]

  emulator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileAndroidEmulator
    container_name: "emulator"
    privileged: true
    extra_hosts:
      - "emulator:127.0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - flutter
    links:
      - flutter
    command: ["/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator", "@flutter_emulator", "-no-skin", "-no-audio", "-no-window"]
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to use that emulator running because, when I execute adb devices in service `flutter` I don't see the emulator that is up and running in service `emulator`.

I've tried to connect through `adb connect` but that's not working. Is there any possible solution that I'm missing or something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

couple fo preconditions need to be met:

- adb-server is running on "emulator" container `adb start-server`
- adb-server see your emulator `adb devices`
- adb-server listen on port 5037
- you are able to reach this port from "flutter" container - check docker networking https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Further reading: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb